# Reinstall SharePoint Server 2010 issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have SharePoint Server 2010 trial version installed on a server. Recently, I removed SharePoint using an uninstaller tool + manual methods because the normal setup file was corrupt and didn't work no matter what I tried. I removed all sites, databases and files. I also made sure the Registry is clean.

Of course that was a wrong move. Now, when I try to reinstall SharePoint Server 2010, I get a message that says: trial editions and licensed editions of sharepoint cannot be installed on the same server.

So I'd be so grateful if someone would suggest any solution to overcome this problem. I don't want to format the server just because of this issue.

Comment: ... just noticed. Why is this question a copy of [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16325/problem-re-installing-sharepoint-server-2010)? This isn't just a duplicate, it's is the same question with some minor reformatting.